# R gvisGeoChart region selection

Tags: r, google-maps, googlevis

I'm using the R package googleVis. Everything is working fine for me, here is my code:

```
month1$latlng<-paste(month1$lat,month1$lng,sep=":")
gvisGeoChart(month1, "latlng", "Err",
         options=list(displayMode="Markers", region='021'))
```

The issue I'm having is with the region selection. What I WANT is North America like this:
 http://www.washlaw.edu/forint/alpha/n/northamerica.html

Right now I have it set to 021 but that's North America completely zoomed out (because it includes ***ALL*** of Canada and Greenland). Then inserting 019 is way too far zoomed out. I've tried US and CA, but none of them give me the exact projection I want.

Is there anyway to manual select multiple regions, like region=c('US','CA') or something? I've tried little things like that and none of them work.

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is really old but in case it's useful to anyone else, I found that most of the UN M.49 codes are valid regions for gvisGeoChart: https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/. There doesn't seem to be one for just the North American countries requested by OP though.